# Can I transmit I2C over RF?

Tags: wireless, i2c, data-transfer, radio

Is it possible to transmit and receive i2c data wirelessly (not via wifi or ssh)

I want to use thumb stick joysticks to move motors wirelessly, at the moment I have two connected to the i2c ports via an ADC. This works fine but I need miles of cable connecting the ADC to the pi! 
I have ordered a cheap 433Mhz RF transmitter and receiver kit Module but can't really see how it could be used to transmit the i2c data?
Is this even possible?
And if so is there any special code il need?

I'm using a raspberry pi 3, and so far all my code is on python 2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I2C is a protocol defined to transmit information between a master and slaves connected to an I2C bus.  The I2C bus consists of a pair of wires with a clock signal and a data signal.

So no, there is no wireless implementation of I2C.

There is nothing to stop you transmitting the data you read from the I2C bus over a RF interface though.

Comment: The problem I noticed is that the rf modules only have one data connection, the others are vvc and ground, what exactly does the clock signal do? Would it work without it?

Comment: While what joan is saying is true, the I2C protocol is bidirectional by nature; you have to make a request (i.e., write) in order to do a read.  So unless the ADC you have is programmable, has some other kind of interface, etc., it won't work with a RF transmitter unless the RF transmitter has an I2C interface, which it sounds like it does not.

Comment: The ADC I have converts the analog signal into I2C,

Comment: @GeorgeDurell Not really, on request from the master over the I2C bus the ADC samples its analogue input and converts it to digital and then sends the digital data to the master over the I2C bus.  Have you looked up I2C on wiki to see how it works?

Comment: Sorry my comment sent accidently, as I was saying the ADC converts it to a digital signal that the i2c can read so how about instead of using (analog joystick--ADC--Rf transmitter--rf reciver--RasPi) what I should do is (analog joystick--RF transmitter--RFreciver--ADC--RasPi) then I'm not transmitting any I2c over RF. it will all be analog until it gets to the reciver the the ADC transforms it into readable digital signal for the i2c on the pi